# Chinese charatcers are looking bolder in mozilla other than chrome & IE

Tags: html, css, utf-8

The URL is http://ca.hoganlovells.com/zh/people. I have used Times New Roman for font family. They are looking perfect in Chrome & IE but in mozilla it's rendering heavier/bolder.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with font family only. Try using below font family

```
font-family: sinkin_sans300_light, "Microsoft YaHei New", "Microsoft Yahei", 微软雅黑, 宋体, SimSun, STXihei, 华文细黑, sans-serif;
font-family: "MS Gothic",sans-serif;
font-family: "MS PGothic",sans-serif;
```

Refer the url: http://www.kendraschaefer.com/2012/06/chinese-standard-web-fonts-the-ultimate-guide-to-css-font-family-declarations-for-web-design-in-simplified-chinese/